# how to check if custom post type column already exists?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, columns

it would be smart to check if a custom column exists when creating the logic for it when building your custom post type. what would the code be to check `if_exists` or similar?

my CPT column code is below:

```
//set up new column to show custom meta value
function site_title_column($column) {
    $column['views'] = 'Title';
    return $column;
}

add_filter('manage_attorneys_posts_columns', 'site_title_column');

//show custom column data
function site_show_title_column($name) {
    global $post;
    switch ($name) {
        case 'views':
            $title = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_site_professional_title', true);
            echo $title;
    }
}

add_action('manage_attorneys_posts_custom_column',  'site_show_title_column');
```

would it be the following?

```
//set up new column to show custom meta value
function site_title_column($column) {
    $column['views'] = 'Title';

    //if this value is blank, then it does not currently exist, 
    //...so output our custom $column:
    if ($column != NULL) {
       return $column;
    } else {
       return;
    }

    add_filter('manage_attorneys_posts_columns', 'site_title_column');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first check, and then assign your custom column.
`$column` should really be `$columns` to convey the real meaning, as it's an array.

So, you need to check if the array key exists before the assignment with something like `isset()` or `array_key_exists()`.

Finally, since your `site_title_column()` function modifies the value of a filter, you should always return a value (usually the original, perhaps modified), as simply calling `return;` returns `NULL` (which is rarely what's needed).

I'd rewrite your function as such:

```
function site_title_column( $columns ) {
    if ( ! isset( $columns['views'] ) ) {
        $columns['views'] = 'Title';
    }
    return $columns;
}
```

Comment: ah ok - checking array key - makes perfect sense! thank you so much for the detailed response. positive energy!